# Solutions for natural numbers $(n,k,m)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have problem to find solutions for natural numbers $(n,k,m)$  of the equation:    $56+63n=11k+2m$,  where $11k=18m$.  Could you help me?  ($n,k,m$ are natural numbers.)

Comment: You could start by noting that 11 divides m and 18 divides k, then resetting k,m accordingly in the rest.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes but I have problem with the rests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$56+63n=11k+2m\Rightarrow 56+63n=20m\Rightarrow 20m-63n=56$$
The last above equation is a *linear diophantine equation*, and since the $GCD$ of the coefficients of variables is $1$, hence it has a solution. By Euclidean method we can write their *$GCD$* as:
$$20(-22)+63(7)=1$$
hence, by multiplying both sides by $56$ we have:
$$20(-22\times 56)+63(7\times 56)=56$$
So as an initial solution we have:
$$m_0=-56\times 22$$ and $$n_0=-56\times 7$$
So the general solution to the above equation will be:
$$m=-56\times 22+63t$$ and $$n=-56\times 7-20t$$
for integer values of $t$. But you must notice that $11k=18m$, hence $11|m$
$$11|m\Rightarrow 11|(-56\times 22+63t)\Rightarrow 11|63t\Rightarrow 11|t$$
Thus if we put $t=11u$ then we can say $(-392-220u,-2016+1134u ,-1232+693u)$ is a solution for the above problem for integer values of $u$

Comment: ,thanks ........:)